# Twitter Bootstrap dropdown misbehavior

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I have two dropdown one have an id and the other have not, and I want to trigger an ajax request and the action to show the dropdown list. 
And this is how Im trying to do it, but has some misbehavior, in this case the ajax request it's triggered but when shows the dropdown list it shows both dropdown list.

```
          <li class="dropdown top-dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" style="padding-right:0;" data-toggle="dropdown">hola</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="/hola"><i class="icon-user"></i>
                  Profile
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/hola"><i class="icon-wrench"></i>
                  Settings
                </a>
              </li>              
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li id="hola" class="dropdown">
            <a id="go_do_something" href="<%= url %>" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" style="padding-right:0;" data-toggle="dropdown">           
              <b id="noti_container">
                <i class="icon-bullhorn"></i>
              </b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">              
                <li>
                  <a href="/hola">
                    <i>added on yesterday</i>
                  </a>
                </li>              
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  See All
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>  
          </li>

$("#go_do_something").live("click", function(){      
    var update_user_last_n = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: update_user_last_n
    }).done(function(xhr, status) {            
      $("#hola").dropdown('toggle');
    }).fail(function(xhr, status) {

    });  

  });
```

In other case I try to use the data-target attribute instead href like describe in [Bootstrap Docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns) but I get an error on the browser:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {url_on_data-target}
```

Answer (score 0):

There most be an elegant way to do this, but here there is a workaround that fix the problem:

```
  $("#go_do_something").live("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();  
    var this_a = this;  
    var url = $(this_a).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: url
    }).done(function(xhr, status) {                  
      $(this_a).removeClass("disabled");
      $(this_a).click();
    }).fail(function(xhr, status) {

    });  

  });
```